# If either *this or *this is clicked, then do *this, or *this respectively

Tags: jquery, function, click

I was wondering if it is possible to do something like this with jQuery:

```
 $('#embedVid' || '#upldImg').click(function() {
  slide($('.vidEmbd') || $('#image_uploader_wrapper'));
 });
```

ie. if '#embedVid' is clicked, then pass '$('.vidEmbed')' to the function 'slide', OR, if '#upldImg' is clicked, then pass '$('#image_uploader_wrapper')' to 'slide'?

It'd be nice if I could put them in one click function...

Thanks

Comment: `'#embedVid' || '#upldImg'` will always send `#embedVid` as the value to jQuery as its the first to evaluate to "true"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could put the target class as the rel attribute of the object...

```
$('#embedVid,#upldImg').click(function() {
  slide($($(this).attr('rel')));
 });
```

with:

```
<span id='embedVid' rel='.vidEmbd'>Some Text</span>$(
```

Comment: Easy and extensible, I like it!

Comment: Love it, great idea, thanks. I actually couldn't get this to work at first, until I realised that you actually need an extra '$(' sign at the beginning, and a ')' at the end for the slide function to identify the element... But the theory is perfect, cheers!

Comment: So, for anyone reading this, the 2nd line should read like this: slide($($(this).attr('rel')));